# Ошибка отправки формы

Tags: javascript, php

Что-то явно делаю не так) Пытаюсь сделать отправку формы на почnу с помощью PHPMailer. С примитивной валидацией на js. Но в этой строке `const response = await fetch('send.php'` я получаю ошибку в консоли 404, и по условию вываливаюсь в ошибку.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  
  const form = document.getElementById('form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', formSend);

  async function formSend(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let error = formValidate(form);
    let formData = new FormData(form);
    formData.append('image', formImage.files[0]);

    if (error === 0) {
      // form.classList.add('_sending');
      
      const response = await fetch('send.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        
        let result = await response.json();
        alert(result.message);
        formPreview.innerHTML = '';
        form.reset();
        // form.classList.remove('_sending');
      } else {
        alert('Ошибка');
        // form.classList.remove('_sending');
      }
    } else {
      alert('Заполните поля!')
    }
  }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ниже есть еще код, но он отвечает за валидацию полей. Файл `send.php` находится там же где и `index`. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а как правильно путь указать? Файл js находится на каталог ниже. Такая запись не решает проблему ../send.php. Если даже перенести этот файл в папку к файлу js, ошибка таже

Comment: Скорее всего из-за того что сервер не может найти путь к вашему файлу. Какой сервер вы используете и какие его настройки?

Comment: Вполне рабочий пример, только что проверил на обычном 20-руб-в-мес хостинге. так что у вас однозначно неправильные пути. Не с вашей точки зрения, а с точки зрения локального сервера.